# How to approximate this summation?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

can anyone help me understand how approximate this summation?

\begin{align}
\frac{r-1}{n} \sum_{i=r}^{n} \frac{1}{i-1}.
\end{align}

I should be able to get

\begin{align}
x\int_{x}^{1}\frac{1}{t}dt
\end{align}

by letting $n$ tend to infinity, writing $x$ as the limit of $r/n$, using $t$ for $i/n$ and $dt$ for $1/n$. (Riemann sum)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Recall that the digamma function admits the following [series representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7#E6)
$$\begin{equation} 
\psi(x+1) = -\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{x+k}  
\right), \quad x >-1, \tag1
\end{equation}
$$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and that [we have](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11#E2), as $n \to \infty$:
$$
\psi (n)= \ln n-\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{12n^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac {1}{n^3}\right).\tag2
$$
Then you obtain
$$
\sum_{i=r}^{n} \frac{1}{i-1}=\psi (n)-\psi(r-1), \quad r>1,\tag3
$$ leading to
$$
\frac{r-1}{n}\sum_{i=r}^{n} \frac{1}{i-1}=\frac{r-1}{n}\ln n-\frac{r-1}{n}\psi(r-1)-\frac{r-1}{2n^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac {1}{n^3}\right)
$$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: This gives the first terms of the asymptotic behaviour, but I think the OP was simply looking for a way to turn his sum into a Riemann sum. Moreover, we can avoid to mention the digamma function by simply writing $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$ as $H_n$ and deriving $(2)$, if needed, by creative telescoping.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I wanted to turn this into a Riemann Sum as @JackD'Aurizio said.